# iTextSharp library read unciode pdf files

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How can i read unicode text using iTextSharp library, here is the example of my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\\Users\\test.pdf");
    string data;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
          data = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
          richTextBox1.Text = data;
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your method already does read unicode text. Probably the pdf you try to extract text from doors not contain the information required for text extraction. Please share (a link to) an example pdf you have trouble extracting text from.

Comment: Hello mkl, thank you for the reply, but i can't share the pdf example.

Comment: That's unfortunate because it means we can't help you any further.